# How to read a log file within a msbuild task and check each line

Tags: msbuild

I want to read a log file created during the build process and check if it contains some error messages. And I want to print out the lines with the error message.

So far I can read the file in and print the whole file out again, but I cannot check several lines for the exception text and print only these lines out. Has someone a hint for me?

```
<Target Name="CheckLog">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <ErrorText>ERR</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ReadLinesFromFile File="execution.log" >
        <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="FileContents" />
    </ReadLinesFromFile>

    <!-- lines are printed out correctly -->
    <Message Text="%(FileContents.Identity)" />

    <CreateProperty Value="true" Condition="@(FileContents.Contains('$(ErrorText)'))">
        <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="VerifyError" /> 
    </CreateProperty>

    <Message Text="@(VerifyError)" />
    <Error Condition="@(VerifyError) != ''" Text="Execution returned with an error." />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by myself.

First I added a condition to the Message Task. So the lines are filtered. Only lines that indicate an error are printed out.

Second I replaced the CreateProperty Task. I use a PropertyGroup now to create a property that contains all lines (not exactly what I wanted initially, but it works for me together with the next point).

And third I modified the error condition. I check if in the whole text an error occurred.

```
<Target Name="CheckLog">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <ErrorText>ERR</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ReadLinesFromFile File="execution.log" >
        <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="FileContents" />
    </ReadLinesFromFile>

    <Message Text="%(FileContents.Identity)" Condition="$([System.String]::Copy('%(FileContents.Identity)').StartsWith($(ErrorText)))" />

    <PropertyGroup>
        <AllLines>@(FileContents)</AllLines>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="$(AllLines.Contains($(ErrorText)))" Text="Execution returned with an error." />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe even more elegant: Using an Error Task, only:

```
<Target Name="CheckLog">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <ErrorText>ERR</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ReadLinesFromFile File="execution.log" >
        <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="FileContents" />
    </ReadLinesFromFile>

    <Error Text="%(FileContents.Identity)" Condition="$([System.String]::Copy('%(FileContents.Identity)').StartsWith($(ErrorText)))" />
</Target>
```